# Angular service not injected in unit test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, requirejs, karma-runner

Hi I have this simple test:

```
define(["angular", "angularMocks", "app", "normalizer"], function(angular, mocks, app) {

  describe("service: normalizer", function () {
    var normalizerService;

    beforeEach(module("ADB"));

    beforeEach(inject(function(_normalizer_) {
      normalizerService = _normalizer_;
    }));

    var params = {};
    var metadata = {};
    var data = {};

    var response = normalizerService.topLanguagesHybrid(metadata, data, params);

    var type = typeof response;
    expect(type).toEqual("object");

  });
});
```

The issue is that the normalizer service is never being set, and in cmd I see the following error:

```
 TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'normalizerService.topLanguagesHybrid')
```

**Note:** I am using requirejs in this project and I can see that normalizer service file is being loaded into the browser (with all of its dependencies). It seems that it just not injected.
What did I do wrong?

[Link to error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=ADB&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:modulerr%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.3.11%2F$injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3DngSanitize%26p1%3DError%253A%2520%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.3.11%252F%2524injector%252Fnomod%253Fp0%253DngSanitize%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fbase%252Fapp%252F3rd-party%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253F8375864b9a1a117f9c599ec881a9fd5b9fde566a%253A21%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520a%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fbase%252Fapp%252F3rd-party%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253F8375864b9a1a117f9c599ec881a9fd5b9fde566a%253A21)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fbase%252Fapp%252F3rd-party%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253F8375864b9a1a117f9c599ec881a9fd5b9fde566a%253A22%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fbase%252Fapp%252F3rd-party%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253F8375864b9a1a117f9c599ec881a9fd5b9fde566a%253A35%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520s%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fbase%252Fapp%252F3rd-party%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253F8375864b9a1a117f9c599ec881a9fd5b9fde566a%253A7)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520g%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fbase%252Fapp%252F3rd-party%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253F8375864b9a1a117f9c599ec881a9fd5b9fde566a%253A36)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fbase%252Fapp%252F3rd-party%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253F8375864b9a1a117f9c599ec881a9fd5b9fde566a%253A35%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520s%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fbase%252Fapp%252F3rd-party%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253F8375864b9a1a117f9c599ec881a9fd5b9fde566a%253A7)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520g%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fbase%252Fapp%252F3rd-party%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253F8375864b9a1a117f9c599ec881a9fd5b9fde566a%253A36)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520Ob%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fbase%252Fapp%252F3rd-party%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253F8375864b9a1a117f9c599ec881a9fd5b9fde566a%253A38)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520workFn%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fbase%252Fapp%252F3rd-party%252Fangular-mocks%252Fangular-mocks.js%253Fb597eac58aae835302b28062a8b8ad2eb2aa1d17%253A2339)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fbase%252Fnode_modules%252Fkarma-jasmine%252Flib%252Fjasmine.js%253F437512c57124d57f5ec77e2e82bfb4e3cdd15cce%253A1145%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fbase%252Fnode_modules%252Fkarma-jasmine%252Flib%252Fjasmine.js%253F437512c57124d57f5ec77e2e82bfb4e3cdd15cce%253A2177%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fbase%252Fnode_modules%252Fkarma-jasmine%252Flib%252Fjasmine.js%253F437512c57124d57f5ec77e2e82bfb4e3cdd15cce%253A2167%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9876%2Fbase%2Fapp%2F3rd-party%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3F8375864b9a1a117f9c599ec881a9fd5b9fde566a:36%0A%20%20%20%20at%20s%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9876%2Fbase%2Fapp%2F3rd-party%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3F8375864b9a1a117f9c599ec881a9fd5b9fde566a:7)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9876%2Fbase%2Fapp%2F3rd-party%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3F8375864b9a1a117f9c599ec881a9fd5b9fde566a:36)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9876%2Fbase%2Fapp%2F3rd-party%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3F8375864b9a1a117f9c599ec881a9fd5b9fde566a:35%0A%20%20%20%20at%20s%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9876%2Fbase%2Fapp%2F3rd-party%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3F8375864b9a1a117f9c599ec881a9fd5b9fde566a:7)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9876%2Fbase%2Fapp%2F3rd-party%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3F8375864b9a1a117f9c599ec881a9fd5b9fde566a:36)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Ob%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9876%2Fbase%2Fapp%2F3rd-party%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3F8375864b9a1a117f9c599ec881a9fd5b9fde566a:38)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20workFn%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9876%2Fbase%2Fapp%2F3rd-party%2Fangular-mocks%2Fangular-mocks.js%3Fb597eac58aae835302b28062a8b8ad2eb2aa1d17:2339)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9876%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fkarma-jasmine%2Flib%2Fjasmine.js%3F437512c57124d57f5ec77e2e82bfb4e3cdd15cce:1145%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9876%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fkarma-jasmine%2Flib%2Fjasmine.js%3F437512c57124d57f5ec77e2e82bfb4e3cdd15cce:2177%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9876%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2F)

Answer (score 1):

When you defining services, you forgot to define normalizer, so the correct syntax for the same is

```
define(["angular", "angularMocks", "app", "normalizer"], function(angular, mocks, app, normalizerService) {

  describe("service: normalizer", function () {
    var normalizerService;

    beforeEach(module("ADB"));

    var params = {};
    var metadata = {};
    var data = {};

    var response = normalizerService.topLanguagesHybrid(metadata, data, params);

    var type = typeof response;
    expect(type).toEqual("object");

  });
});
```

Comment: I am getting the same error + plus this new error: `service: normalizer encountered a declaration exception FAILED
`

Comment: it is the same error :(. I think I have to inject it somehow. thanks for the help

Comment: Seems like ngSanitize script file is not included in your test runner or the module is not loaded, do you use ngSanitize inside your ADB module?, if so, try adding it as a dependency.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to define the it, for the test scenario, beforeEach runs before each "it" function.

```
define(["angular", "angularMocks", "app", "normalizer"], function(angular, mocks, app) {

  describe("service: normalizer", function () {
    var normalizerService;

    beforeEach(module("ADB"));

    beforeEach(inject(function(_normalizer_) {
      normalizerService = _normalizer_;
    }));

    it('should define topLanguageHybrid method', function() {
      var params = {};
      var metadata = {};
      var data = {};

      var response = normalizerService.topLanguagesHybrid(metadata, data, params);

      var type = typeof response;
      expect(type).toEqual("object");
    });
  });
});
```

More info on jasmine: [jasmine docs](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html)

Comment: Still getting error that says that there is some issue with injecting the service

Comment: Here is the error I am seeing in my console: http://prntscr.com/5ygtz8. I am using the code you posted.

Comment: See question for the error link (angular error explanation)